# Build size differs when on different platforms

Tags: java, ant, jar, cross-platform

I am  building a certain CVS tag on two platforms - CYGWIN running on WINXP and RED Hat LINUX. For the same tag build on CYGWIN xx.jar is  590173 bytes but on Linux box it is 589927 bytes.

Should I be concerned? Rather, what could be the reason for different build sizes?

Answer (score 2):

If you have text files in your Jar the newline separator may be different. On windows it is two characters and on Linux it is one. From the sizes I would say you have at least 250 lines of text.

BTW: if you run Java in CYGWIN, you are actually running the Windows version I assume.